# SQL view syntax

Tags: mysql, view

so I have a table I want to create a view with, but not entirely sure how to go about it..

So lets say we have a table with:

- Index
- Country
- City
- Population

and I want to make a view showing each country and the sum of it's population, it sounds easy, but I am having trouble wrapping my head around the SELECT used to create the view.

Just standard mySQL if it makes any difference.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL could be something like:

```
SELECT country, SUM(population) as total_population
FROM table 
GROUP BY country
```

Answer (score 0):

To create a view in MYSQL:

```
CREATE VIEW v_country_population
AS
SELECT country, SUM(population) as total_population
FROM cities 
GROUP BY country
```